# What is the default gnome terminal size?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Question is simple, when you hit `ctrl+alt+t` what size is the terminal that pops up?
If you like you could also say how you retrieved this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it easily by running the `resize` command:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ resize
COLUMNS=80;
LINES=24;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

I found it by using `apropos` and looking for the `terminal settings`

```
~$ apropos "terminal settings"
resize (1)           - set environment and terminal settings to current xterm..
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default terminal size is 80×24.

In Ubuntu 16.04, you can change this default by opening a terminal, right clicking on the terminal window and opening the Profile. Here, you can set the `Initial terminal size` on the `General` tab.